# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'baselines.common'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, baseline

I ran the following code in Google Colab:

```
    from baselines.common.atari_wrappers import make_atari, wrap_deepmind
```

And got the following error:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'baselines.common'
```

I tried !pip install baselines, but it didn't fixed the issue.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following instruction:

```
!apt install swig cmake libopenmpi-dev zlib1g-dev
!pip install stable-baselines[mpi]==2.8.0 box2d box2d-kengz
```

[from](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiHn_qypIjuAhXcSxUIHUg5D8EQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1L_IMo6v0a0ALK8nefZm6PqPSy0vZIWBT&usg=AOvVaw2atF9MiFpz9WSHQHk1BVuI)

Comment: We do also would have to run this `%tensorflow_version 1.x`..... and change the line `from baselines.common.atari_wrappers import make_atari, wrap_deepmind` to `from stable_baselines.common.atari_wrappers import make_atari, wrap_deepmind`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install baselines
```

Comment: Running that code downloads some stuff and prints this: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status. And then does not fixes anything

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to an [outdated version](https://github.com/openai/baselines/issues/429). This issue used to be encountered and was later fixed in an update. Updating / Installing the latest version should do the job.